# Cannot Play Farmville in Fullscreen

Tags: firefox, flash

I am using Kubuntu 13.04 in my HCL Laptop which has i5 processor, Nvidia GT 520M Graphics, 4GB of Ram and the problem is that I cannot play Farmvilla in full screen mode or zoom much. It even doesn't show the full screen button. What might be the problem ?

Comment: The problem is with flash, not with Ubuntu...

Comment: @Alvar Thanks! for your reply. Do I need to reinstall flash.

Comment: What browser are you using? try to purge flash and then install it. A reinstall might just do it.

Comment: @Alvar I am using firefox latest version.